# HTML element is hidden on click after $.get()

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm trying to create a fairly simple drill down menu to load some pages into a div using `$.get()` in jQuery. Everything is working as intended, except for one issue. Once the HTML is loaded successfully via a `$.get()` call, any click on a main drill link other than the link in the active list item results in the `#menu-list` being hidden via `display: none;`. I'm sure that I'm missing something very simple here, but I can't seem to spot the error.

Here is my **HTML**:

```
<div id="menu-container">
    <ul id="menu-list">
        <li class="main-drill">
            <a href="/somepage">Main Drill 1</a>
        </li>
        <li class="main-drill">
            <a href="#">Main Drill 2</a>
            <ul>
                <li class="sub-drill"><a href="/somepage">Sub Drill 1</a></li>
                <li class="sub-drill"><a href="/somepage">Sub Drill 2</a></li>
                <li class="sub-drill"><a href="/somepage">Sub Drill 3</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="main-drill">
            <a href="#">Main Drill 3</a>
            <ul>
                <li class="sub-drill"><a href="/somepage">Sub Drill 1</a></li>
                <li class="sub-drill"><a href="/somepage">Sub Drill 2</a></li>
                <li class="sub-drill"><a href="/somepage">Sub Drill 3</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div id="main-content">
    The main HTML content is displayed here.
</div>
```

My **jQuery** code:

```
$('#menu-container > ul > li > a').live('click', function(e) {
    var url = $(this).attr('href');

    if (url == '#') {
        var parentElement = $(this).parent();
        var checkElement = $(this).next();

        $('#menu-container li').removeClass('active');
        $(this).closest('li').addClass('active');

        if ((checkElement.is('ul')) && (checkElement.is(':visible'))) {
            $(this).closest('li').removeClass('active');
            parentElement.children('ul').slideUp('normal');
        }

        if ((checkElement.is('ul')) && (!checkElement.is(':visible'))) {
            $('#menu-container ul ul:visible').slideUp('normal');
            parentElement.children('ul').slideDown('normal');
        }

        if ($(this).closest('li').find('ul').children().length == 0) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
});

$('#menu-container > ul > li > ul > li > a').live('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var url = $(this).attr('href');

    $.get(url, function (response) {
        $('#main-content').html(response);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you are adding elements dynamically, try this:

```
$(document).on('click','#menu-container > ul > li > a',function() {

//code

});
```

This is a common issue with AJAX-loaded content, in that old handlers no longer apply to dynamically added content, unless you use event delegation, as shown above.

Additionally, instead of *document*, use a selector for the closes parent element of *#menu-container > ul > li > a*.